# Edge browser blank debugging tool for certain sites

Tags: browser, frontend, microsoft-edge

There is a specific site/domain where the Edge browser will load the site but have completely blank debugger tool (elements tab, network tab, every tab, console output at all levels, everything blank).  There is no inspect option when right clicking elements on the page as well. It does not do this for other sites/domains.  Chrome works fine for all.

Unfortunately I cannot share the actual site as it is an internal site within my organization.  But just wondering if anyone has encountered this sort of behavior?

Comment: Hi, have you tried my suggestions? How do they work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here're some suggestions for you:

1. Make sure your Microsoft Edge is in the latest version.
2. Restore DevTools. Go to DevTools settings --> Preferences --> Restore defaults and refresh.
3. Check whether it is caused by installed extensions.
4. Reset Microsoft Edge. Go to Edge settings --> Reset settings --> Restore settings to their default values.
5. Try Edge Insider channels like **Edge Canary**.